# How can I let user input the name of text file again if the name of file doesn’t exists?

Tags: java

i want to ask user to input the file name if it doesn’t exist the program should ask the user to again input the name until the file is found and also if you can check my picture encryption code is correct.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter filename");
        String filename = in.nextLine();

        // Selecting a file or image for Eecryption.
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(filename);
        

        //// Converting Image into byte array, create a
        // array of same size as Image size
        byte data[] = new byte[f.available()];
        String str = new String(data);
        f.read(data);
        char key = 'z';
        int i = 0;
        String file1 = new String(data);
        System.out.println("File content is:\n" + file1);
       

        // Encryption
        for (byte b : data) {
            data[i] = (byte) (b ^ key);
            i++;
            

        }
        FileOutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        f1.write(data);
        

        // Closing the files
        f.close();
        f1.close();
        System.out.println("Encryption Done...");
        String file2 = new String(data);
        System.out.println("File content is:\n" + file2);
        
        // Decryption
        int j = 0;
        for (byte b : data) {
            data[j] = (byte) (b ^ key);
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a while to let the user enter a filename until it is a valid one

Comment: If you are allowed to use a GUI, you could use Java's file chooser.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html